# Replace output of an array

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I´ve this array:

```
Array
(
[result] => Array
    (
        [class] => 11
```

I echo out the `[class]`

```
 $items2 = $r['result'];
 echo " ".$items2['class']." ";
```

Now i get the for example the 11. I want to replace the output number like that:

```
11= Bird
12= Cake
13= Bear
```

I know that i can use `str_replace`. Can you help me a bit with the structure?

Comment: `echo $items2['class'] . "= Test".$items2['class']." ";`?

Comment: Where are 12 and 13 coming from?

Comment: where is the rest of array ? u can just concatenate the output echo $item2['class']."=Test".$item2['class'];

Answer (score 0):

Replace in array:

```
foreach($array as $result => $class){
   $array['class'] = "Test".$array['class'];
}
```

OR

Replace only when outputting:

```
  foreach($array as $result => $class){
       echo "Test".$array['class'];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think you missunderstood my question. The class can be another output then the 11 , for example 12, or 13. So i want the number automatically get replaced with a word. For this i need the str_replace. I´ve edited my initial post to make it more clear.

Comment: actually you've changed your post since I answered.... In that case do a switch statement and just reassign the position value.

Comment: Thank you, i searched the switch statement!